# ~ちった meaning/grammar

Tags: grammar, casual

「って、いい加減にしろー！」
「ありゃ、怒られちった」

What ~ちった　means in this sentence ? Only translation i found is ちる (+ past form), but in this case phrase has no sense for me. Is it some casual suffix or what ?

Thanks for your answers!

P.S. solved, ~ちった is contraction for ～てしまった (accidentally/finish completely, past)

Comment: Are you sure it's ちった and not ちゃった?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me this looks like  a further shortening of 〜ちまった, itself a contraction of 〜てしまった.
I.e. the second sentence is something like “Oops, (she’s) mad now” (lit. “I’ve got her angry”).

**EDIT** it seems it’s used this way in Northern Tohoku according to [this Asahi article](http://www.asahi.com/area/tokyo/articles/MTW20170821131340001.html)